# Installing the Framework (Problem cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: cache-proxy)

Tags: api-platform.com

I tried to install api-platform: https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/

after starting I see in the log "api-platform-242_cache-proxy_1"

```
│   Error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│   Message from VCC-compiler:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│   Expected return action name.                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│   ('/usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 67 Pos 13)                                                                                                                                                                                                     │
│       return (miss);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   ------------####--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│   Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│   VCL compilation failed
```

If I use the api (post greeting), the response code is 500 
"hydra:description": "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: cache-proxy (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",
  "trace": [

Nevertheless the entity is still inserted.

Furthermore I tried the api-platform without docker (Apache). 
I removed the line VARNISH_URL=http://cache-proxy in the .env file.
Then the return code is 500 with
"cURL error 3:  malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

Do you have any idea?

Kind regards
Ludi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove varnish from api_platform.yaml

Comment: Well... I had the same issue and removing Varnish from configuration solved it, but... if the distribution is meant to be an easy pre-configured introduction, why is it misconfigured from the start? I'm novice when it comes to Docker, I've heard about Varnish, but nothing more, I'm not yet experienced with Symfony4 (but I work with Sf3). So it's very frustrating for me when a pre-configured Docker-based application doesn't work from start. What is wrong with the distribution? How to enable varnish caching? Is there a container missing or misconfigured?

Comment: It works , The distribution completely runs in docker. It is meant to help you in development , not deployment .  

If you want to deploy it on Apache , Shared hosting, AWS ,Microwave , or whatever based on your need you have to modify. Same things with environment variables .

Comment: But I'm deploying it in Docker. I see a container "cache-proxy" that should've provided Varnish. I see in docker-compose logs the very same error @Ludi did. And yes, disabling Varnish works, but it is not a satisfactory answer for me and I think it is not a satisfactory answer to the above question in the general sense.

Comment: In fact I cannot even say it works this way. `cache-proxy` fails, so `h2-proxy` fails and therefore HTTPS access to API doesn't work and in result the admin component doesn't work, because it has somehow hardcoded that it tries to connect to API via HTTPS on port 8443.

Comment: Is the docker container on your local pc. It works perfectly fine for local development.

Comment: I've got everything on local my local PC on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have the same issue on a different installation of Ubuntu 18.04. And please refrain from telling me "it works", when I clearly see it does not.

Comment: I have it running on Docker for windows as well as Manjaro arch. Try rebuilding with the docker-compose build.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should remove or comment out `VARNISH_URL=http://cache-proxy` from `.env` file not from `api_platform.yaml` as your `.env` can change and is/should be host dependent and configuration (`.yaml`) should not.

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#the-env-file-environment-variables

> There is also a .env file which is loaded and its contents become environment variables. This is useful during development, or if setting environment variables is difficult for your deployment.

In `api_platform.yaml` you SHOULD comment out whole `http_cache` section or you will keep getting cURL errors about malformed  from guzzle.

> `{
>     "@context": "/api-platform/api/public/contexts/Error",
>     "@type": "hydra:Error",
>     "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
>     "hydra:description": "cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",
>     "trace": [
>       {
>         "namespace": "",
>         "short_class": "",
>         "class": "",
>         "type": "",
>         "function": "",
>         "file": "...\\api-platform\\api\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
>         "line": 186,
>         "args": []
>       },`

Effect is the same.

Comment: Please note, the `h2-proxy` container depends on `cache-proxy` container. So (at least in my case) with failed Varnish I have no HTTPS and in result, for example, the Admin component fails as well.

Comment: I checked yesterday and commenting out just Varnish is enough although I did not check if any HTTP caching is left working. I also used tar.gz standalone version so it does not work exactly as docker one ex. HTTPS does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I resolved it!

As specified here: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/777, the problem is the directories/files rights, so instead of downloading the zip or tar.gz archive, I cloned the repo,

All commands I made (after installing Docker for Windows and enabling Shared Drives in Docker for Windows settings):

```
cd my_parent_directory
git clone https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform.git
cd api-platform
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

And when I go on https://localhost:8443 all work!!

I hope this helps you :)