# How to access administration component in API Platforms distribution 2.4.2?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, api-platform.com

I tried to set up API Platform on my local machine to explore it.
I tried to performed all the operations according to API Platform's "Getting Started" page. So I downloaded the latest offical distribution which happens to be v2.4.2 (https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/releases/tag/v2.4.2) and I started it using Docker.

I cannot however access the administration backend at `http://localhost:81` receiving "Unable to retrieve API documentation."

I searched for help at https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/getting-started/, but it describes steps that seems to be already done in the distribution

How can I enable the admin component or debug what went wrong?

Edit (2019-04-14)

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
40a5d5213cfe        quay.io/api-platform/nginx    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   45 hours ago        Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp            apiplatformdemo_api_1
d53711c0ba0c        quay.io/api-platform/php      "docker-entrypoint p…"   45 hours ago        Up 6 minutes        9000/tcp                        apiplatformdemo_php_1
2d4eb8d09e3e        quay.io/api-platform/client   "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   45 hours ago        Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp            apiplatformdemo_client_1
abe3e3b41810        quay.io/api-platform/admin    "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   45 hours ago        Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:81->3000/tcp            apiplatformdemo_admin_1
4596a7f81cd8        postgres:10-alpine            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   45 hours ago        Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp          apiplatformdemo_db_1
c805fc2f11c9        dunglas/mercure               "./mercure"              45 hours ago        Up 6 minutes        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1337->80/tcp   apiplatformdemo_mercure_1
```

Edit 2 (2019-04-14)

It is worth mentioning that although the API component at `http://localhost:8080` works, the HTTPS variant at `https://localhost:8443` does not. (Connection refused if I try to `telnet` it.)

Now it turned out it escaped my notice earlier that there is a message in the JS console saying there was a failed connection to `https://localhost:8443`. (It says about CORS, but I think the real reason is 8443 simply refuses connection). So although I entered the HTTP variant of Admin at `http://localhost:81` it tried to access the API via HTTPS. What could be the reason HTTPS doesn't work?

Edit 3 (2019-04-15)

After looking into the logs of docker compose, I see it is relevant the Varnish container failed. `h2-proxy` depends on it and it is `h2-proxy` that governs the `8443` port.

```
cache-proxy_1  | Error:
cache-proxy_1  | Message from VCC-compiler:
cache-proxy_1  | Expected return action name.
cache-proxy_1  | ('/usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 67 Pos 13)
cache-proxy_1  |     return (miss);
cache-proxy_1  | ------------####--
cache-proxy_1  | 
cache-proxy_1  | Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
cache-proxy_1  | VCL compilation failed
apiplatform242_cache-proxy_1 exited with code 2
h2-proxy_1     | 2019/04/15 08:09:17 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "cache-proxy" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:58
h2-proxy_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "cache-proxy" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:58
apiplatform242_h2-proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: It should live at the location you mention. What do response do you get? Can you access the others part like the API component at port 8443? Does `docker container ls` contain a mention of an admin container?

Comment: The API component at 8080 responds fine, HTTPS does not -- haven't investigated yet. I had to disable Varnish, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591888/installing-the-framework-problem-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host-cache-pr

I added the response of `docker container ls` to the question.

Comment: Your docker output looks good. Do you get a result from the server if you are logged into it? Log into the server: `docker exec -it apiplatformdemo_admin_1  /bin/ash;` try to get index.html via `wget http://localhost:3000`. If this downloads an index.html file you can be pretty sure docker and the admin component are running correctly. I would start looking at network issues such as a blocked port 81 or a port 81 is already in use by another service. Have you tried turning it on and off? :)

Comment: `wget http://localhost:3000` downloads some HTML. It is the same content I get when I get the source of what Admin component displays...

I've just realized however something else that somehow escaped my notice earlier: In the JS console,  there is a failed CORS request  because -- although I entered `http://localhost:81/` -- it tries to obtain something from `https://localhost:8443/` and is blocked on the Same Origin Policy...

Comment: The admin is trying to load API information from `https://localhost:8443`. Oh yes, the CORS check. That is defined in the `api/.env` by default `CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$`. Should work if you try to connect from http://localhost:81 though. But you can check it out over there.

Comment: Well, it's the distribution, so everything is set with the default values: and so there is `CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$` in `api/.env`.

Please, have in mind HTTPS doesn't work right now and it seems it's hardcoded somewhere. I saw it for example in `admin/.env` containing`REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT=https://localhost:8443`, although changing it to `http://localhost:81` didn't help with the Admin component.

Comment: Have you visited https://localhost:8443 and accepted the certificate issue? Anyway, maybe update your Question with all findings, maybe some-one else has a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: No certificate issues. Simply connection refused at 8443. And yes it's a good idea to update the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error by getting API Platform by cloning the current master and not download the tar.tgz release version (2.4.2)

```
git clone https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform.git
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Works like a charm !

Comment: They've got `return (restart);` instead. That's a hint.